# Called sibling component method not updating view in other component Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

Data binding is not working in Angular 2.
   name is not getting updated on call of method.
   Not able to update the view in secApp component on calling updateNameSibl() 
   method from app.ts updateName() method.

adding more details -- 
I have a situation like two views for two components, from one component I want to update the view of second component. Updating button is available in first component. I can not use parent child relationship as the second is independent of first component. Want both components available all time.

Please find my plunker -- [myplunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zyIQc09Uu78zsYHyITRC?p=preview)

Thanks in advance.

app.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div (click)=updateName()>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  secAppObj:secApp;

  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
    this.secAppObj = new secApp();
  }

  public updateName(){
    console.log("inside updateName")
    this.secAppObj.updateNameSibl();
  } 
}


secApp.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'sec-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>I am second {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class secApp {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `sandeep`
  }
  public updateNameSibl(){
    console.log("inside updateNameSibl")
    this.name = `sandeep2`
  }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't `secApp` a child of `App`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @San, Please put some more details in the question and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

Solution:-

Updated Plunker link:- https://plnkr.co/edit/4T834ZEcjPh2TzyP1uPn?p=preview

### app.ts

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {secApp} from './secApp'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div (click)=updateName()>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <sec-app ></sec-app>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  secAppObj:secApp;

  @ViewChild(secApp) child:secApp;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
    this.secAppObj = new secApp();
  }

  public updateName(){

    console.log("inside updateName")
   this.name  =  this.child.updateNameSibl();
  } 
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, secApp ],
  bootstrap: [ App, secApp ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### secApp.ts

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'sec-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>I am second {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class secApp {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `sandeep`
  }
  public updateNameSibl(){
    alert('hi');
    console.log("inside updateNameSibl")
    return `sandeep2`;
  }
}
```

Comment: Question is not much clear, so, in the current scenario, this may be useful to user until and unless , he may ask to rectify.

Comment: This change not updating secApp. Both component view should be available all time, secApp component name should be updated on change in app component.

Comment: You want 'name'  in app.ts to be updated in secApp.ts on the call of method updatename () in app.ts?

Comment: Not necessarily I want name in secApp get updated on call of the method updatename()-- As of now I am hard coding not even this value is getting updated